# The [placement] tag has been displaced

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement) has no wiki, no followers, and over 200 questions. Most of the questions seem to revolve around positioning graphical elements, but there are a some odd-ball topics like [replica placement policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968731/how-to-read-replication-factor-value-in-hdfs), [memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963050/c-allocation-in-a-fixed-block-of-memory-in-a-loop), and [some WPF class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746679/why-isnt-contextmenuservice-placement-working-at-all).

In terms of topic, this tag adds nearly no value to questions. It isn't useful for browsing or searching, and its meaning won't be clear unless you get it from the question, the title, or other tags (by which time you don't need this tag to understand what the question is about). For graphical placement, this is often obvious from the other tags involved ([grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grid), [jqplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqplot), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) to name a few). There is a [placement-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement-new) about a C++ language feature, so some of the questions should be retagged to that. I didn't see any other uses where it offers anything over being mentioned in the title.

Kill it with fire?

Answer (score 19):

Agreed, this tag is still a total jumble of completely unrelated things, up to 218 questions now since we never got around to actual burnination in 2015, it seems.

Everything visual involves placement of things on a 2D or 3D layout, and methods for doing so vary wildly depending on web vs. desktop.  There's no way someone can be an expert in that, or that you'd need a tag for it instead of just using the word as a normal search term.

And there are still lots of mis-tagged questions about C++ [placement-new].

There are even fully generic uses like [An attempt to generate a certain amount of randomly-placed numbers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447495/an-attempt-to-generate-a-certain-amount-of-randomly-placed-numbers-in-an-array) that just tagged some words from the title.  Or placement of statements wrt. each other or on a line or something, [in COBOL source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504942/dot-rules-in-nested-conditional-statements-cobol).

Comment: If it weren't for the fact it will get burned anyway I would have said fix the mistagged placement-new questions then analyze.

Answer (score 8):

[placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- For questions about the `new` operator in C++ when it's used at already allocated memory, use [placement-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement-new)
- For questions about memory management, use [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management)
- For questions about memory allocation, use [allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/allocation)

## Progress:

The [placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=placement),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplacement%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplacement%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplacement%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplacement%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=307542)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.